# Authenticate and move existing excel file to sharepoint webfolder using C#

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Using a valid user name and password, how can I send an existing excel file to a web folder (Sharepoint document)?

For example, the file I want to send is

```
C:\Source.xls
```

And I want to send it to:

```
\\somesharepointintranetwebsite.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\somefolder\
```

However when I try to do this with a normal copy function, I get the error that it cannot find the path (this is before I log in manually to the web folder I created on my local box).

How do I log in using C# programming so that I can 'always' move the file without issue?

Answer (score 0):

This authenticated off the command line.
    net use \someserversite.com\somefolder /USER:DOMAIN\username password